# left operand has type 'std::stringstream (__cdecl *)(std::string)'

Tags: c++, stringstream

what the diff in two codes blow:

```
char buf[2048];
stringstream in(string(buf));
int tmpInt;

while ((in >> tmpInt)) { // wrong, error C2296: '>>' : illegal, left operand has type 'std::stringstream (__cdecl *)(std::string)'

}
```

and

```
char buf[2048];
string tmpStr(buf);
stringstream in(tmpStr); 

while ((in >> tmpInt)) { // right

}
```

I think they do same thing: both use string to construct a stringstream object. No matter temp object or a real object, we will call string copy constructor in stringstream(just copy buf content)

IDE: `vs2010`

So, what the different between this two ways ?  or stringstream implement ways .

thanks.

Comment: It's the most vexing parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris gave away the answer. The code is the equivalent of the following:

```
stringstream in(string buf);
```

In C++, people call this [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

The compiler sees it as a function declaration. `in` is a function which returns a stringstream and accepts a `string` as an argument. Note that your compiler is telling you this in the error message `std::stringstream (__cdecl *)(std::string)`.

You will need an extra set of parentheses or C++11 uniform initializer syntax to tell the compiler its not a function you are declaring:

```
stringstream in((string(buf)));

stringstream in{string(buf)};
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. Compile think it's a function forward declare. thanks Jesse.